# Command to switch main display scaling to 100%

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, highdpi

When opening WinForms controls/forms in Visual Studio 2022 on my high DPI display, this message is being displayed:

[image]

> Scaling on your main display is set to 150%. Restart Visual Studio with 100% scaling

I could then click the link and Visual Studio starts with 100% scaling.

When I accidentally forget to click the link and instead closed the form, and then open it again, the message is gone:

[image]

What I do then is be restart Visual Studio, open the form again, see the message again, click it and finally get Visual Studio in 100% scaling mode.

I would avoid this extra restart just to get the message with the link again.

#### Question

Is there a hotkey, menu item or command in Visual Studio 2022 to restart the IDE with 100% scaling?

Comment: I do not know of a menu command, but there are ways to start VS as DPI-Unware. See: [Disable DPI-awareness to address scaling issues with Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2022:

Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt

```
devenv /noScale
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2019

Comment: VS Code will follow your default display scale setting for your laptop. If you want to change it so that you won't have to restart, then change your default Settings > Display to 100% (125% percent is recommended by the system when you're not developing.)

Answer (score 4):

Modify Shortcut : Just Right Click on visual studio icon and click on properties.

[As Seen in Screen Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLOOR.png)

then modify target by adding /noscale command at the end of exe name and path.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /noScale

[as seen in screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF2D0.png)

Simply Click ok and open visual studio with 100% scaling and automatic scaling disabled always.
no e

Answer (score 3):

As I was also looking for this, I'll post this as an answer; this is documented in @TnTinMn's link. You need to open a `developer command prompt` and enter the following command:

```
devenv /noScale
```

This will launch VS as if you clicked on "Restart with 100% scaling". On Windows I recommend creating a shortcut on the taskbar for the dev prompt (pin it on the taskbar) which for VS2019 Enterprise is located here:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

This will save the "extra" restart (so 1 restart instead of 2). Tested on Win10, VS2019.
For VS2022 Enterprise:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```